# Complex analysis: Cauchy Intergral exercise

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

[image]

I got the answer being $10\pi i\cos(5i)$ by using the Cauchy integral formula for derivatives, with $n=1$, and $g(z)= \sin(5z)$, making the derivative by $5\cos(5z)$.

Is it wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Think you could help me now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It appears the given answer was incorrect.  You used the chain rule correctly (apparently).